# When to use poisson distribution vs weibull distribution?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, weibull-distribution

I have a simulator which simulates the jobs processed on different machines. I wish to model production of defective parts on the machines. So on a machine, I can model the time before the next defect happens. So should I consider Weibull distribution or Poisson distribution? How to choose? I do not have any data to fit and its up to me to decide the characteristics of the machines.

Comment: Is this what you meant to ask? The time between defects will be a continuous measurement whereas the Poisson distribution is discrete.

Comment: @Scortchi Yes. But still I am not clear. Arrival times are modeled using Poisson. Why not Weibull?

Comment: If arrival *times* are modelled as having an exponential distribution, then the *counts* of arrivals over a given time interval have a Poisson distribution. See [Relationship between poisson and exponential distribution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2092/17230).