# Poisson process: getting a poisson from an exponential assumption

Tags: probability, poisson-process

In a poisson process, getting an exponential distribution from a poisson assumption (for eg. in a given period of time $t$, if number of books that arrive is given by a Poisson, then the time until first email will be given by an Exponential) is pretty straightforward, for eg. see [Relationship between poisson and exponential distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/relationship-between-poisson-and-exponential-distribution).

I'm trying to get the opposite. Given that each new email arrives following an exponential distribution, how can I retrieve that the number of emails in a time period $t$ is given by a Poisson?

I can get the basic cases. For example, let $X_i$ be time to receive $i$th email after having received $(i-1)$th email, and assume $X_i \sim Expo(\lambda)$. Also let $Y$ be the number of emails received in time period of length $t$.

Then
\begin{align*}
P(Y=0) &= P(\mbox{no book arrives before time } t) \\
&= P(X_1 > t) = e^{-\lambda t}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
P(Y=1) &= P(\mbox{first book arrives before time }t \mbox{ but then no other book arrives until time }t) \\
&= \int_0^t P(X_0 = x) \cdot P(X_1 > t-x) \,dx \\
&= \int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \cdot e^{-\lambda (t-x)} \,dx
= \int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \,dx = \lambda t e^{-\lambda t}
\end{align*}

which are both Poisson. We can continue this process, for example
$$ P(Y=2) = \int^t_0 P(X_1=x_1) \left[ \int^t_{x_1} P(X_2=x_2) \cdot P(X_3>t-x_2) \,dy \right] \,dx$$

But this quickly becomes unwieldy. Is there a better method to get this result? For example, I just learned that a sum of exponential r.v. (eg. the $X_i$'s here) can be modeled using a Gamma distribution, but not sure if this is of any help.

Answer (score 6):

I'll leave it to you to fill the details of this:

The exponential waiting time implies that an infinitesimal interval of length $dt$ will have probability $\lambda dt$ of seeing a jump. Since the process we generate from these exponentials is memoryless, it resets on every hit. A region $[0,t]$, can be broken into bins of length $t/n$. As $n$ goes to infinity, each interval approximates an infinitesimal. Each bin is independent of all others. Thus the number of jumps in such an interval $[0,t]$ is asymptotically a *binomial* distribution with $n$ bins and probability $\lambda t/n$ of each bin getting a hit. Thus we get:

$$P(Y=x)=\binom{n}{x}(\lambda t/n)^k(1-\lambda t/n)^{n-k}.$$

Now use your favorite method of showing that a binomial with $n$ bins whose probability scales like $c/n$ approaches a poisson distribution with parameter $c$. You could use Stirling's approximation on the above, or even easier, recall that the characteristic function of a binomial looks like $(1-p+pe^{ix})^n$. The characteristic function of a poisson with rate $\lambda t$ is $\exp(\lambda t (\exp(ix-1))$. Then the definition of $e$ implies:

$$(1-p+pe^{ix})^n=(1-(1-e^{ix})\lambda t/n)^n\rightarrow \exp(\lambda t (\exp(ix-1)).$$

Comment: Why is the probability of seeing a jump in a $dt$ interval $\lambda dt$? Isn't it $\int_0^{dt} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx = 1-e^{-\lambda dt}$?

Comment: Sure, but $dt$ is infinitesimal, so $1-e^{-\lambda dt}=\lambda dt + o(dt)$ (taylor expand the exponential around 0). This reasoning will make the argument rigorous.

Comment: Oh wow nice! Is there a more intuitive way to reason/remember that this probability is $\lambda$ (for example using expected value somehow... or...?)? Or did you just do this calculation but left it out of your answer?

Comment: Maybe the easiest way is to actually derive the exponential waiting time. So we assume that the chance of something occurring in a bin of size $1/n$ is asymptotically $\lambda/n$. We are waiting for the first such occurrence, which gives $P(T=x)=(1-\lambda/n)^x (\lambda/n)$. If we scale $x$ like $cn$, this asymptotically gives you $P(T\in (c,c+dt))\approx\lambda \exp(-\lambda c) dt$, which is precisely the density of the exponential.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of approaching this problem. Suppose $X_i \sim Exp(\beta)$. For simplicity, define $T_k = \sum_{i=1}^k X_i$. Finally, we define

$$N = \min(n \ \ s.t. \ \ T_{n-1} < 1 \text{ and } T_n \geq 1)$$

Then it follows that $N-1$ is a Poisson random variable with mean $\frac{1}{\beta}$.

---

We notice that $T_{n-1} \sim Gamma(n-1, \beta)$ and that $T_{n-1}$ and $X_n$ are independent and thus the joint pdf is easily attainable. In order to leverage this fact, we write:

$$\begin{align*}
P(N=n) &= P(T_{n-1} < 1, \ T_n \geq 1)\\
&= P(T_{n-1} < 1, \ T_{n-1} \geq 1 - X_n)
\end{align*}$$

We can obtain this probability by integrating the joint pdf $f(x, t)$ over the appropriate domain.

$$\begin{align*}
P(N=n) &= \int_0^1\int_{1-t}^\infty f(x,t)\ dx\ dt \\
&= \int_0^1\int_{1-t}^\infty \frac{e^{-t/\beta}t^{n-2}}{(n-2)!\beta^{n-1}}\cdot\frac{e^{-x/\beta}}{\beta} \ dx \ dt \\
&= \frac{e^{-1/\beta}}{(n-2)!\beta^{n-1}}\int_0^1 t^{n-2} \ dt \\
&= \frac{e^{-1/\beta}(1/\beta)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
\end{align*}$$

If we make the simple transformation $Y = N-1$, and define $\lambda = 1/\beta$ we obtain:

$$P(Y=y) = P(N=y+1) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^y}{y!}$$

Hence $Y = N-1$ is Poisson as desired.

Comment: $T_k$ I'm guessing is the sum of $X_i$'s? But $X_i$ and $\beta$ seem to be circularly defined, so I'm a bit loss.

Comment: Yes, I just use $T_k$ to avoid having to type out so many sums. And $\beta$ is just the parameter of $X_i$'s distribution. There are two common ways to parameterize the exponential distribution, by stating $\beta = E(X_i)$, i was just trying to be explicit with which parameterization I was using. (:

Answer (score 1):

For $P(Y=2)$ and beyond, I used the result for the previous integer and constructed a proof by induction. followed the same method

To motivate the proof, for $Y=2$
$$
\begin{align*}
P(Y=2) &= \int_0^t P(\text{First arrival at $t_1 < t$ and exactly one arrival between $t_1$ and $t$}) dt_1 \\
&= \int_0^t \lambda \exp(-\lambda t_1)\lambda(t-t_1)\exp(-\lambda(t-t_1)) dt_1 \\
&= \lambda^2 \exp(-\lambda t) \int_0^t (t-t_1) dt_1 \\
&= \lambda^2 \exp(-\lambda t) t^2/2 \\
&= \frac{(\lambda t)^2 \exp(-\lambda t)}{2!}
\end{align*} $$

In the above, $\lambda \exp(-\lambda t_1)$ is the pdf for the first arrival time, and $\lambda(t-t_1)\exp(-\lambda(t-t_1))$ is the probability of having exactly one arrival between $t_1$ and $t$. The total probability of having exactly two arrivals is given by integrating over $t_1$ from $0$ to $t$.

##### Proof by Induction

Let $P(Y=k) = \frac{(\lambda t)^k \exp(-\lambda t)}{k!}$, the result of the Poisson process. Then

$$
\begin{align*}
P(Y=k+1) &= \int_0^t P(\text{First arrival at $t_1 < t$ and exactly $k$ arrivals between $t_1$ and $t$}) dt_1 \\
&= \int_0^t \lambda \exp(-\lambda t_1)(\lambda(t-t_1))^k\frac{\exp(-\lambda(t-t_1))}{k!} dt_1 \\
&= \frac{\lambda^{k+1} \exp(-\lambda t)}{k!} \int_0^t (t-t_1)^k dt_1 \\
&= \frac{(\lambda t)^{k+1} \exp(-\lambda t)}{(k+1)!}
\end{align*} $$