# Proving that the average number of arrival events as $\lambda t$ given the inter-arrival duration are i.i.d. Exp($\lambda$) random variables

Tags: markov-process, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

I'm trying to prove a common result for the Poisson process but I'm stuck.

> Given $T_i$ are i.i.d. $Exp(\lambda)$ random variables (where $\lambda$ is the rate)
> that represent the duration of arrival events and $N(t) = \textrm{max} \{ n: \sum_{i=1}^{n}T_i \leq t \}$ is the number of said events within the interval $[0, t]$, prove that the mean of $N(t)$ is $\lambda t$.

Intuitively it makes a lot of sense: if the average duration between the events is 2s, then in a 10 second duration then the average # of events would be 5. But I wanted to see it mathematically.

My strategy was to use the exponentially distributed durations to get a mathematical expression that I can say resembles a Poisson with mean of $\lambda t$. I ended going down the path using the fact that $Y_k = T_1 + T_2 + \ldots T_k \sim Gamma(k,\lambda)$ and getting a product of Gamma CDFs:

\begin{align}
P(N(t) = k) &= P(Y_k \leq t, Y_{k+1} > t) \newline
&= P(Y_k \leq t) (1 - P(Y_{k+1} < t)) && (T_i\text{ are i.i.d.}) \newline 
&= \bigg( e^{-\lambda t}\sum_{i=k}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda t)^i}{i!} \bigg) \bigg( e^{-\lambda t}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{(\lambda t)^i}{i!} \bigg) && \text{from Wikipedia}
\end{align}

which looks kind of close but I couldn't get further.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/relationship-between-poisson-and-exponential-distribution and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294982/poisson-process-getting-a-poisson-from-an-exponential-assumption