What distribution describes the duration until a first poisson event occurs?
Imagine you have 100 individuals observed for 100 days. Every day, each individual has a 10% chance of an event occurring. What is the distribution in duration until the first event?
Empirically it can be observed as follows (this is R code):
n <- 1e4
duration <- 100
risk <- 0.1
count <- rpois(n, duration * risk)
events <- mapply(sample.int,
                 n = duration,
                 size = count)
first_event <- sapply(events, min)
hist(first_event, main = '10% risk of event per time increment', 
     xlab = 'time')



Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so,
please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its
wiki.

You can find quite a lot about this topic by searching our site for Poisson process time.

Since this is about discrete time rather than continuous time, you're dealing with a Bernoulli process rather than with a Poisson process.

@gung-ReinstateMonica it's not from a course or text book - I'm simulating survival data

Probability of zero events.

This has been answered before: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/relationship-between-poisson-and-exponential-distribution
